# Subquery using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

I am trying to write a query which excludes meter_nos with three of the same date values ie. a 1-3 relationship.

The query must only show meter_nos which have different dates, i.e a 1-1 relationship.

Can anyone help? I am stuck

Heres a sample below:

```
 ...and a.mtr_id in (select b.mtr_id 
                from ci_mtr_config b
                where a.mtr_id=b.mtr_id
                 group by b.mtr_id
                 having count(b.mtr_id)=3)
   and a.mtr_id not in (select f.eff_dttm
                 from ci_mtr_config f
                  where a.mtr_id=f.mtr_id
                   group by f.eff_dttm
                  having count(f.eff_dttm)=3)
```

This does not work.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and the code you have tried.

Comment: You will get faster answers if you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve *(and follow the advice above)*

Answer (score 1):

Try using **COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ....)** to count the number of rows sharing the same meter and date. Then filter by that calculation.

```
CREATE TABLE CI_MTR_CONFIG
    (MTR_ID INT, EFF_DTTM DATE)
;

INSERT INTO CI_MTR_CONFIG
    (MTR_ID, EFF_DTTM)
    VALUES
    (303, to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')),
    (303, to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')),
    (303, to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')),
    (202, to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')),
    (202, to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')),
    (101, to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
;

select
    *
from (
      select
          *, count(*) over(partition by MTR_ID, EFF_DTTM) as count_of
      from CI_MTR_CONFIG
      ) d
where count_of = 1
```

Only meter 101 would be returned from the sample data above.

Note if EFF_DTTM information is more accurate than day use TRUNC()

```
count(*) over(partition by MTR_ID, TRUNC(EFF_DTTM)) as count_of
```

Comment: how do i display the count_of =1  in the main query , it isnt working 
  @used_by_already

Comment: Include **count_of**  in the srkect clause.  If the query isn't  working you have not implemrnted it correctly. Check it again.

Comment: By the way there is a difference between "not working" and "not meeting my needs".  Not working to me says it  produces an error and hence you have not implemented  correctly. The sample query does run without error.

Comment: mmm, if you literally want 'count_of =1' in the result, use **select 'count_of =1' as x** in the top select clause where x is a heading you provide that column